# how to program Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I wanna create matrix like following;

I am still beginner of this language and I need help so badly, thanks

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create list of lists and print them as you like

```
matrix = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    matrix[i][i] = 1
    print " ".join(str(num) for num in matrix[i])
print matrix
```

**Output**

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1

[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: This really ought to be in the tutorial; instead, the tutorial gives much more complicated examples of comprehensions and 2D indexing, only going to the obvious (matrix) example when things get difficult, in [Nested List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning to do any real work with matrices, you should strongly consider looking at [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org).

Once you get it installed:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = np.diag([1]*5)
>>> print(matrix)
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

So far, not too exciting. But check this out:

```
>>> print(matrix * 2)
[[2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0 2]]
>>> print(matrix + 1)
[[2 1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 1 1 1]
 [1 1 2 1 1]
 [1 1 1 2 1]
>>> print((1 + matrix) * (1 - matrix))
[[0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0]]
>>> print(np.arccos(matrix) / np.pi)
[[ 0.   0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.   0.5  0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0.   0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0.5  0.   0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0. ]]
```

All that math, and a whole lot more, you don't have to implement yourself. And it's generally at least 10x as fast as if you *did* implement it yourself. All that, plus fancy indexing (like slicing by row, column, or both), and all kinds of other things you don't yet know you were going to ask for, but will.

Comment: Could you please tell me how it will be 10x faster?

Comment: @thefourtheye: Because (a) it does the loops in C instead of in Python, (b) it can often take advantage of SIMD/vector processors, and (c) it doesn't have to "box" and "unbox" values to do math on them. As a rule of thumb, if you can express your expression in NumPy (without having to use the `vectorize` function), it's at least an order of magnitude faster. (With PyPy instead of CPython, of course it's less… but it's still significant, which is why the PyPy people are putting so much work into NumPyPy.)

Comment: +1 because numpy > doing it manually.

Comment: @abarnert +1. Cool :) It looks like fun. I should learn it. Thanks for the heads up, master :)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Obviously I agree or I wouldn't have written this answer… but it's definitely worth learning how to do it all manually. In fact, figuring out how to implement a small subset of NumPy in pure Python (with lists of lists, or, if you want to get a clever, a flat list and a shape tuple) is a great learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

My way will be ...

**Code:**:

```
size = 5
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        print 1 if i==j else 0,
    print ''
```

**Output:**

```
1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If you just want to print it out, and not do anything else with it, sure. But thefourtheye's solution (or using an array library like NumPy) means you actually have a matrix you can store and work with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most simple. please enjoy it

```
def fun(N):
    return [[0]*x + [1] + [0]*(N-x) for x in range(N)]
print(fun(5))
```

The result:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```